# fix: 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodemon, node-debugger

What is fix, if found error message ***nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. *** after hitting command ***nodemon index*** in your node project the

Comment: install nodemon globally. npm install -g nodemon

Answer (score 3):

you need to ***nodemon*** install globally.
using this command

`npm install -g nodemon --save-dev`

Answer (score 2):

Install Nodemon like

```
npm install nodemon --save-dev
```

nodemon is require for development purpose only, so use -dev for this.

Answer (score 0):

At First Need To Install Nodemon Module.
So go to the project dir. Then open terminal. 
And paste the code And Press "Enter"

```
npm install nodemon --save-dev
```